# send a list of ul to form in django

Tags: django, django-forms

In a template I have two connected lists, one of which is initially empty. The user has to choose up to three options from the left list, add them to the right list, order them (according to his/her priorities) and then send it back.

it looks like:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li value="1">Item A</li>
  <li value="2">Item B</li>
  <li value="3">Item C</li>
  <li value="4">Item D</li>
  <li value="5">Item E</li>
  <li value="6">Item F</li>
  <li value="7">Item G</li>
</ul>
</div>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
 <!--here goes the initially empty list-->
</ul>
```

and in {% scripts %} block:

```
<script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
    } );
 </script>
```

in models.py I have a field to store the selected info:

```
preferences = CommaSeparatedIntegerField()
```

The problem is how to POST info from the updated ul (`sortable2`) back to the database? I can add a hidden field `preferences` to the page and then fill it using jQuery, but it seems like an ugly solution. What is the right one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to POST the updated ul (sortable2) back to the database, then one of the possible solution is that the **ul (sortable2)** should be inside a **form** whose data you can submit using POST method.

Now when any of the **li element is moved** from the ul (sortable1) to ul(sortable2), then an **input type element** is also **inserted** in the ul (sortable2) along with the list element, where **"value" attribute** of the input will have to be the **same as the li element** in the ul (sortable1) was. Also the type of this input element will be **hidden**.

So now when you'll submit this form using a submit button, you'll get all the data back in your views and hence can make changes to your database accordingly.

Comment: " then an input type element is also inserted " - do you mean it will be inserted automatically as soon as I get ul(sortable2) into a form, or I should add input type myself?

Comment: You will have to write an onClick function for the button clicking on which the elements are moved from ul(sortable1) to ul(sortable2). In that function you will have to create a div and then an input type element and then append that element to that div using javascript.
See this for a an example of how to append add an input field or in general divs and elements to html using javascript -> https://github.com/amyth/hammer/blob/master/static/js/main.js
See the populate function and how input elements added to div and how their properties & attributes have been set.